# Python, RPi + MCP3008 + 2xForce Sensitive Resistor - Square

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a MCP3008 connected to RPi and 2 x [Force Sensitive Resistor - Square](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/force-sensitive-resistor-hookup-guide) connected to the MCP3008. The sensors are laying side by side horisontal on my desk and I can read and print the data (0-100) from both sensors (sensor1 and sensor2) separately. I just can't come up with any idea of python code to detect when I touch sensor1 (left) and move my finger to sensor2 (right).

In addition I need to know how many milliseconds it takes from that I touch sensor1 until I lifted from sensor2.

```
from time import sleep
from gpiozero import MCP3008

sensor1 = MCP3008(1) # Pin 2 on the ADC
sensor2 = MCP3008(2) # Pin 3 on the ADC

# Read data from the ADC
def getData(readSensor):
    value = readSensor
    rawValue = value.value
    return rawValue

while True:
    print('Sensor1 = {0:.0f}'.format(getData(sensor1)*100))
    print('Sensor2 = {0:.0f}'.format(getData(sensor2)*100))
    print('')

    sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Do you know how to use an if statement to detect when the pressure on your sensor is above a certain threshold - so you can recognize that as a "press"? Then you feed the 'press's to some logic which starts timers...

Comment: Yes I know if statement to detect pressure, sorry I forgot to write it.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to timestamp the events and then use the time stamps to determine what action to take. Something like the below might help you.

```
if getData(sensor1) > TOUCH_THRESHOLD:
    sensor1LastPressedAt = time.time()
```

Do the same for sensor2 and compare the time stamps.

(TOUCH_THRESHOLD is the value that you measure to be someone touching the button)